# 60 V 200 A isolator contacts wearing

Tags: batteries

We have two 80 A motor controllers running on a 55 V lithium battery. Our current isolator is rated at 300 A. Our motor controllers typically draw 40 A under load.

We are having issues with the isolators prematurely failing due to contact arcing, presumably due to the high voltage DC and the motor controller inrush current.

The battery isolator is cycled on average 10 times per day, whilst not in use and to change over batteries.

The motors are stopped using the motor controllers and therefore the isolator is only used at zero motor current. We have observed a large inrush current as there are 4 x 4700 uf capacitors.

We have tried a number of isolators, including a Flipsky anti-spark switch. We attempted a high-value resistor to pre-charge the caps. Whilst this worked, it required the user to hold a "charge button".

With your help and advice We are now in talks with Allbright to spec up a suitable contactor and using a programable timer to turn on the contactor, a suitable sized fuse will protect the resistor should the contactor fail to close.

[image: contactor pre charge]

https://www.arc-components.com/sw180b-8-albright-single-acting-solenoid-contactor-48v-continuous-6644.htm

Comment: Make and model of the contactor? Is there anything preventing you from using MOSFETs instead?

Comment: Contactor Switches must be derated over 50% with DC motors and your 40A motor will be ~400A on startup (each) but burn up the contacts without a power snubber when open unless you have wiring & battery ESR resistance.

Comment: The solution is to design it properly and understand what actually happens so that you can specify a contactor that is suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the isolator is a no-name 300A marine battery isolator, which out of 30+ machines only one has failed within 6 months, however, we feel this is likely to increase.

We fitted a snubber across the switch 0.1uf 47ohm however we could still hear the contacts arcing.

Is the arcing a function of the voltage 55Vdc or the high inrush current for the capacitors?

Comment: What are the actual specs of the isolator - a marine one would (typically) be 24v rated and the 300A would be peak current for a few seconds while the motors crank. If you don't fully understand the problems, speaking to the sales department of a reputable manufacturer of hardware (EG Albright) they'll be able to take an informed guess at what will actually work for you. Switching big loads reliably is expensive, buying cheap isolators is unlikely to work out long-term whatever you do.

Comment: Oh! It's not a contactor. That isolator is not rated to break any load current what so ever. You need to rethink this. I would still suggest MOSFETs to do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, We are in talks with Allbright to spec up a suitable Contactor we may also require a pre-charge circuit before closing the contacts. https://www.arc-components.com/sw180b-8-albright-single-acting-solenoid-contactor-48v-continuous-6644.html

Comment: You won't need the user to hold a button if you automate the start-up with a timer. I have done that with a custom BLDC motor controller, a small relay or MOSFET used to precharge the capacitors while the load is held in the off state.

Comment: As said before, your most recent comment is new information and should be edited into your Question. Otherwise, readers have to piece all of this together to understand it. It's now hidden in a sea of comments. Please rewrite the question text as needed to contain this info (don't just dump it at the end under an 'EDIT' heading). You can embed the link, it's very easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Snubbers** are a rather vague collection of multi-variable designs. {polarity(s), voltage, current, power, energy}

AC and DC snubbers are different designs.

Although mechanical switches, relays or (large current) Contactors in small DC motors < 1Hp are largely obsolete, the snubber designs to protect the switch are unique.

The mechanical switch in air when turned off must arc in order to extinquish inductive current as the contact gap starts small when it opens and therfore MUST arc (unless moving at impossible speeds of 1 us faster than ionization)  The decay time of current depends on the voltage rise to the clamp voltage during when it is high impedance then the low impedance clamp of the TVS being Rs , Tau=L/R until the current drops below the arc holding current just like an SCR in principle.

When the motor inductive surge voltage T=L/R drops below the back EMF or generator voltage, the snubber current is zero and the motor coasts to a stop from friction.
A speed brake with be a short circuit or pulsed brake or an electronic PWM controlled switch to control the rate of de-acceleration demands a lot of energy to be absorbed but stops quickly.

here's a tutorial on R, RC , TVS snubber designs.

### modus operandi

First define your design goals (SPECS) for control of motor and protection of switch in measurable terms. Then think about design questions to ask yourself.
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11160.pdf